# Xamarin forms Picker control issue (android, appcompat)

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Create blank XF app, apply app compat and material design following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/) guide
2. Add Picker control to main page with some items (doesnt matter what)
3. Start app (tested on device 5.0 and emulator 4.4), try to fast double tap on pickers EditText field - it causes opening of two AlertDialog (or whatever) with pickers elements to select. When you choose some element or touches cancel button top dialog dismisses and shows underlying (we tapped twice and if we was fast enough - got two dialogs). Selecting any item or cancel button on second dialog we getting NullReferenceException (sender - AlertDialog, "this" Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer), stack trace here:

> at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer.b__9_2
>   (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs args) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent2\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\PickerRenderer.cs:110
>   at
>   Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListenerImplementor.OnDismiss
>   (IDialogInterface dialog) [0x0000d] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Content.IDialogInterface.cs:369
>   at
>   Android.Content.IDialogInterfaceOnDismissListenerInvoker.n_OnDismiss_Landroid_content_DialogInterface_
>   (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_dialog) [0x00011]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Content.IDialogInterface.cs:334
>   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:b6f021d2-c6e1-4672-9b03-e892d275f304
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)

Without appcompat I cant reproduce it, at least I cant get two dialogs show.
Seems like by selecting value on second dialog, we are trying to access somethig from dismissed one and getting exception. Any suggestion how to work around with that?

Comment: Can you upload a reproduction of this or maybe file a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/)? I'm not getting the issue with the latest stable as you describe it, but I could be doing something wrong, here. Just helps to have your context.

Comment: This issue discribed here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41717  with attached reproduction project.

Comment: Bug status set as confirmed, so until fixing we are to use completely custom renderer or just change in Picker renderer base class to original (non-compat) PickerRenderer. By the way original pickers dialog (as DatePicker too) also can be opened twice, but this not causing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just merged in a [fix](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/257/files) for this and the changes should be available beginning with the 2.3.2 prereleases.